# How to Scroll to Newly added row in datagrid in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a data grid which is bind Observable Collection. When i click on add new button i will add New row to collection. How can i Scroll to new row in pragmatically.

data grid XMAL

```
<DataGrid SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIntex}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsKeySet}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="dgwTemplateDetails" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding OrderTemplateList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrderTemplate}" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="auto">

      <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Srl No" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding SrlNo}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Act Code" Width="75" Binding="{Binding ActCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Act Name" Width="275" Binding="{Binding ActName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="No. Of Days" Width="75" Binding="{Binding NoOfDays, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Cutting" Width="75" Binding="{Binding IsCutSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

VM Add Row Function

```
if (ValidateHeader())
{
  if (OrderTemplateList == null)
    this.OrderTemplateList = new ObservableCollection<EventManagementTemplate>();
  EventManagementTemplate obJEvent = new EventManagementTemplate();
  obJEvent.BuyerCode = this.BuyerCode;
  this.OrderTemplateList.Add(obJEvent);
  int no = 1;
  this.OrderTemplateList.ToList().ForEach(m => m.SrlNo = no++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do the following:

1. Name your dataGrid so that you can access it in your code behind file (the .cs file that is paired with the xaml file containing your datagrid)
2. Add a delegate to your view model to be called by the AddRow function - the delegate should take, as a parameter, the object you want to be scrolled into view.
3. Have the code behind that contains the data grid subscribe to the delegate ==> basically the code behind is supplying a call back to your view model. The code behind's callback will be the code that scrolls to the new item.
4. The callback should call the data grid's ScrollIntoView function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.scrollintoview(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. At the end of your view model's Add Row function (after you have added the item) call the delegate with the item to be scrolled into view.

Sample Code:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   // declare the delegate signature...
   delegate void ScrollIntoViewDelegateSignature(EventManagementTemplate objEvent);

   // create a pointer to the delegate that can be set by the code behind...
   public ScrollIntoViewDelegateSignature ScrollIntoView {get; set;}

   protected AddRow()
   {
      .. your code here

      // call the delegate...
      if (ScrollIntoView != null)
         ScrollIntoView(objEvent)
   }
}

public class MyControlOrWindowThatContainsDataGrid : UserControl/ChildWindow/Page
{
   public void Initialize()
   {
      ...your code here
      // set the scrollIntoView delegate...
      myViewModel.ScrollIntoView = ScrollIntoView;
   }

   // create a ScrollIntoView function
   // ==> the return value and parameters MUST match the delegate signature
   public void ScrollIntoView(EventManagementTemplate objEvent)
   {
      myDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(objEvent);
   }
}
```

Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx

In my opinion it would be best to do this using an event, but that is more complicated.
Here is msdn documentation on how to use events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: I don't have idea to how to add delegata function to the View Model. Can you describe it bit.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my answer to explain delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Behavior for DataGrid. Here in this code it scroll to last row of the grid only when new row added to collection. You can modify it for any condition. There are some delay added which was required sometimes. You can exclude if not required.

```
public class AutoScrollToEndBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    private DateTime _lastCollectionChangedTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        SubscribeToCollectionChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        UnsubscribeFromCollectionChanged();
    }

    private void SubscribeToCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.Items is ICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            collectionView.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void UnsubscribeFromCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.Items is ICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            collectionView.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            _lastCollectionChangedTime = DateTime.Now;
            Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - _lastCollectionChangedTime).TotalMilliseconds > 100)
                {
                    ScrollToEnd();
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }

    private void ScrollToEnd()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var lastItem = AssociatedObject.Items[AssociatedObject.Items.Count - 1];
            AssociatedObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In XAML,

Add following code above closing tag of datagrid `</DataGrid>`

```
     <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <behavior:AutoScrollToEndBehavior/>
      </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this after adding item inside DataGrid :

```
dgwTemplateDetails.ScrollIntoView(obJEvent);
```

This line will scroll to the element which is currently added.